# two buttons with the same "onClick" - Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying out Android. Initially I had this:

[image: original plan]

I created an extra button called "Reset". I lined them up in a row by using the layout Table Row, which looks like the following:

[image]

The "Calculate" has been assigned to the string "clickHandler", and its clickable property is also assigned to "clickHandler".
I basically got this tutorial off here
[Tutorial site](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#first)

So far my code looks like this

```
package ywong02.android.temperature;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Convert extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private EditText text;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }

    public void myClickHandler(View view){

        RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        Button resetButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        switch(view.getId()){       
        case R.id.button1:
            if(text.getText().length() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a number to convert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());

                    // second attempt: make Reset button onClick to False initially
                    // resetButton.isClickable();

            if(celsiusButton.isChecked()){
                text.setText(String.valueOf(convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue)));
            }
            else{
                text.setText(String.valueOf(convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue)));
            }
            // switch to the other button
            if(fahrenheitButton.isChecked()){
                fahrenheitButton.setChecked(false);
                celsiusButton.setChecked(true);
            }
            else {
                fahrenheitButton.setChecked(true);
                celsiusButton.setChecked(false);
            }
            break;  // don't forget to break at each case!!!
        case R.id.button2:  // reset button
            fahrenheitButton.setChecked(false);
            celsiusButton.setChecked(true);
            //text.setText("");
            //text.setText(null);
            break;

        }
        return;
    }

    private float convertFahrenheitToCelsius(float fahrenheit) {}
    private float convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(float celsius) {}
}
```

The first attempt:

1. (1) assign both buttons clickable to
   Default (from properties) 
   [main.xml]
2. (2) with and without the setText in
   the the second switch case

Result:  Error Msg from Android  --> Application was forced to stopped

Second attempt:

1. assign the reset button's clickable property to False
2. add the extra
   resetButton.isClickable() to the
   java source code
3. with / without the setText

Result:  Reset has no effect (I can't even click on
    it. it doesn't seem like it is
    clickable!!)

My real problem is to how to get the reset button working.

Is it wrong to assign both button to the same "onClick"  (in this case, it is called myclickHandler)??

If the answer to the previous question is YES, then I must create two separate classes, one handles the reset, and the other handles the calculate button. Am I right??

Thanks!

---

Update (posting XML - this one assign both buttons to Clickable (Default))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/bgColor">
<EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"></EditText>
<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radioGroup1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RadioButton android:text="@string/toCelsius" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/radio0" android:checked="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton android:text="@string/toFahrenheit" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/radio1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RadioButton>
</RadioGroup>
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:onClick="myClickHandler" android:text="@string/pressToCalc" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:onClick="myclickHandler" android:text="@string/clickToReset"></Button>
</TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please describe your problem better. I'm not sure what you're asking. But to answer what question I do see... the reason that a switch case is used is, for a compact way to find out WHICH view was clicked. In android, views include buttons and each of these have an ID. So knowing which clicked it allows you to have one listener for several buttons by using the ID to filter.

Comment: the code looks fines, so i would assume the xml is at fault.

Comment: @ JoxTraex. I just revised the post. Please take a look. Yes. You did answer one of my questions. I assigned the same "onClick" attribute (in this case, myClickHandler) to both buttons, and I provided a case for each button

Comment: @ techi I also added the XML. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what you had said so far and based on what I can tell of your programming skills/understanding of Java.. I believe the issue of why its not working is because you didn't register your reset button to a listener, so its not being listened to.

**This is just a guess**

**Update**

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:onClick="myClickHandler" android:text="@string/pressToCalc" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:onClick="myclickHandler" android:text="@string/clickToReset"></Button>
```

IT IS CAP-SENSITIVE!!! Careful!!

You dont have the same listener for each:

```
(Button1) android:onClick="myClickHandler"
(Button2) android:onClick="myclickHandler"
```

Comment: I also can not see you setting the onClick listener and your activity does not implement it.

Comment: woo. you are right. thanks Jox. I couldn't catch this at all.

Comment: Keep practicing, just takes some time to understand it. There are other ways you could do it, but have fun!

Comment: I am sorry for asking such a dumb question. but thanks to all 3 of you. I will work on my Java skill :/

Comment: Also my philosophy is : "You have to get it wrong, before you can get it right" I say this because when you get it wrong, if it ever happens again, you will know what to do. However; Put forth the effort to learn what its doing and it'll help you solve these problems much easier. Learn the basics is my suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

From what you have posted...

The reset button doesn't work because the switch statement doesn't catch it.  Assign an ID to the reset button in your XML and add a case for the reset button ID in your code.

Edit:

For button2 you mismatched the spelling of the click handler method.

Comment: I think I had a case for the reset button, whose id is button2

Answer (score 1):

In layout/main.xml for my activity, I have defined a button thusly:

```
    <Button
         android:id="@+id/locate_button"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/locate"
         android:onClick="displayCurrentLocation" />
```

This causes the `public void displayCurrentLocation(View view)` method in my activity to be called.  I have other buttons whose `android:onClick` attributes cause them to call other methods in this activity when clicked.  Consequently, if it works better for you, I would recommend having your two buttons call two separate methods in your activity using the `android:onClick` attribute in your `layout.xml` file.